# How to debug/trace incoming SFTP conversations?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, sftp, debugging

My application (JetBrains CLion) connects to my remote server by `SFTP` and places files to there. Unfortunately, files are appearing filled with zero bytes. I want to trace, what goes wrong.

Can I run something on my server to monitor `SFTP` sessions in real time and see, what is happening. I am a `root` on the server. Server runs Ubuntu 16.

P.S. If I run `SFTP` myself and `put` files, they are ok.

---

On client side I don't see any problems in logs: just some session with `put`, `stat` and similar commands with `Ok` outputs. So would like to debug server side too.

Comment: I do not think that OpenSSH SFTP server can do debugging that low level to explain  why *contents* of an uploaded file gets corrupted -- Shouldn't you rather debug your application? It's most probably sending a wrong contents.

Comment: You can set [LogLevel](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#LogLevel) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  This will give you more information about what is happening on the server side.  However the problem might be on the client side which wouldn't show much in the server-side longs no matter how much information you log.

Comment: You're on the wrong track. It's your client app which is broken. But yes, you can attach with strace or ltrace to the sftp server and see in real time what it's doing. I bet that it's reading the zeroed blcks from the client.

Comment: If the `put` and `stat` is the lowest level of debugging you have done on the client side, then you haven't done any real debugging. SFTP protocol **does not even have textual commands**.

Comment: You can be pretty sure that sftp-server will be writing the data its told to disk. So assuming its possible to see the unencrypted packets, and they are all full of null characters, what do you plan on doing next?

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenSSH server](https://www.openssh.com/) uses a program named [sftp-server](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) for SFTP sessions. `sftp-server` has a couple of options to control logging:

> **-f log_facility**
>   Specifies the facility code that is used when logging messages from sftp-server. The possible values are: DAEMON,
>   USER, AUTH, LOCAL0, LOCAL1, LOCAL2, LOCAL3, LOCAL4, LOCAL5, LOCAL6,
>   LOCAL7. The default is AUTH.
>
> **-l log_level**
>   Specifies which messages will be logged by sftp-server. The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO,
>   VERBOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2, and DEBUG3. INFO and VERBOSE log
>   transactions that sftp-server performs on behalf of the client. DEBUG
>   and DEBUG1 are equivalent. DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify higher
>   levels of debugging output. The default is ERROR.

To apply these, you open your system's [sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) file and find the `Subsystem` line for SFTP. It will look like one or the other of these two lines:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /path/to/sftp-server
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp
```

Whatever you have append the logging arguments to the end:

```
Subsystem   sftp    /path/to/sftp-server -l DEBUG3
```

After editing `sshd_config`, you must restart `sshd` for the change to take effect.

Once you've done all this, SFTP sessions should start logging debug information to syslog. You can use the debug messages to track the commands sent by a client and the filesystem operations which the SFTP server performs.

The sftp-server program is written in C and you can find source code [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable). If you can understand it, you'll probably find the source code helpful to understanding the log messages.